# How can I solve this partial differential equation? Wolfram alpha can't interpret it right.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I stumbled upon a differential equation which I do not know how to solve but would love to know the answer. I tried plugging it in wolfram alpha but it didn't help. For some reason WA wasn't interpreting it right.

$$ \frac{ \partial y}{\partial x} \bigg( { \frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial \epsilon \partial x}\bigg) } = 0 $$

I am looking for $y(x, \epsilon)$ with these conditions:
$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} {(0, \epsilon)} = 0$$
$$y(x, \epsilon_0) = y(x, -\epsilon_0) = h$$
where $h \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$

If not analytical, can someone at least give me a hint as to what the numerical solution would like so that I know, intuitively, if this model is right.

Comment: Wolfram alpha isn't alone: I can't interpret it right either. In particular, it is not clear to what you apply the $\partial\over\partial\epsilon$.

Comment: It is being applied to the next term, the $dy/dx.$

Comment: Good. So in effect, we have a product of three terms, the last of which (the square root) is never 0. Is that right?

Comment: I updated it and yeah you're absolutely right.

Comment: So we may just skip the third term, can't we? OK, then $\partial y\over\partial x$ is a peculiar function of $\varepsilon$: either it is 0, or its derivative is 0. Looks like the constant 0 is the only function that fits.

Comment: So, you don't think there is any non-trivial solutions?

Comment: If the equation is to hold _almost everywhere_ (that is, everywhere but a few points), then there are piecewise-constant solutions. If it is to hold strictly everywhere, then yes, I don't think anything non-trivial is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have put it in Mathematica:

```
DSolve[D[y[x, e], x]*D[y[x, e], {x, 1}, {e, 1}]*Sqrt[1 + (D[y[x, e], x])^2] == 0 
&& (D[y[x, e], x] /. x -> 0) == 0, y, {x, e}]
```

and I got a simple linear solution in $\epsilon$

{{y -> Function[{x, e}, C[2][e]]}}

in other words: $y[x,\epsilon]= C(\epsilon)$.

So the derivative of y in x is always zero but the boundary condition equal to h will be satisfied simultaneously only for even function $C(\epsilon)=C(-\epsilon)$.

Comment: Hey can you clarify what $C(\epsilon)$ is? I can't understand this notation.

Comment: It means it is a function of $\epsilon$ only: $y(x,\epsilon)=y(\epsilon)$, in other words that is is a constant in relation to the derivative in x.